# Geometry Node: object deforming along curve, applied to multiple curves?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Learning about geometry nodes here...
I am wanting to create a field of objects (let's say trees) and have them bend into the wind.
All this using geometry node.

Most approaches I found would usually rotate or move the position of a mesh, which gives a sense of wind, but remains stiff-looking, as the vertex do not move.

So, I found this one approach which I find excellent in how it feigns a wind simulation (also nicely pedagogical tutorial).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7KLYUuaS8M

Although, the tutorial only shows the method with curve that are then turned into meshes.

I have played around and tried to understand these nodes so to ultimately couple this approach and apply it to already modeled objects.
Hence, to use the curves for deforming (let's say) tree objects.

I somewhat get the idea that the objects should 'follow' the curves.
I am able to do that with one object following or deforming along one curve.
But I am incapable to find a way to assign an object to multiple curves and deforming alongside these curves while using this method.

[image: Here is the node system, following the said tutorial]

Maybe someone has a hint onto how to organize the nodes to make it happen?

Thank you :)